# C++ virtual method, that doesn't require "this" pointer - optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, virtual-functions

I'd like to implement access to a certain class:

```
class A { some properties and methods };
```

The problem is there are multiple states A can be in and the methods need to behave accordingly. One way is this:

```
class A
{
    void Method1() { 
        if (A is in state 1) { do something }
        else if (A is in state 2) { do something else }
        ...
    }
};
```

That obviously isn't very optimal, if the methods are called many times. So a solution, which is simple to implement, would be to create several classes for different states:

```
class A
{
    class State1 {
        virtual void Method1(A& a) { do something; }
        ...
    } State1Instance;

    class State2 { ... }
    ...
};
```

And then manage a pointer to the object depending on current state (e.g. State1Instance) and call methods of this object. That avoids the CPU consuming condition.

BUT the State# methods also receive the completely useless "this" pointer to the State object. Is there a way to avoid this? I know the difference is minimal, but I'm trying to make this as optimal as possible and using a CPU register for a completely pointless value is not ideal. This would actually be a good use for "virtual static", which is forbidden however.

Comment: You can build your own thunk table.  You can do it with metaprogramming, by hand, the preproc...  Lots of options.  Too large a scope for this forum.  You could start with googling up "Cooperative Visitor", which implements a thunk table via template metaprogramming and such.

Comment: And you verified that the compiler doesn't optimze it away?

Comment: Use switch. Will be faster. Unless you dont know all states upfront. Otherwise use virtual function and dont bother with this, compiler might optimize it away (or might not), but in grand scheme of things performance penalty will be meaningless anyway. Your bigger worry will be slowdown from memory allocation - preallocate some buffer and use new placement.

Comment: Classes in C++ do not have properties.

Comment: Question; The "this" pointer does serve purpose during over-riding variables as it will try to refer to the variable that is within the current scope, and it helps serve to understand code from an etiquette standpoint. Is this really that big of burden that it needs to be dropped?

Comment: Many conditions do not necessarily result into a performance drop. As long as you are not on an embedded system CPUs would do branching prediciton, so there might not even be a difference if the conditions are present or not. Virtual tabels on the other hand might have a larger overhead. The biggest problem for performance is if the CPU cannot make use of its cache. You should search for some talks about this topic. Because those kind of optimisations will have a larger effect.

Comment: From my experience this could cause quite a CPU overhead. But it's hard to say, I may try both indeed. Anyways @manni66 compiler cannot optimize this probably, because it cannot know if the "this" isn't used in some override.

Answer (score 1):

Just use good old function pointers if you're really concerned about the repeated branches, which usually you shouldn't.

```
struct A
{
    using StateFn = void (*)(A&);

    static void State1(A& a) { a.i = 42; }
    static void State2(A& a) { a.i = 420; }

    void Method1() { s(*this); }

    StateFn s = State1;
    int i;
};
```

If you have multiple methods associated with each state, a table of methods can be constructed as such

```
struct A
{
    static void State1M1(A& a) { a.i = 42; }
    static void State2M1(A& a) { a.i = 420; }

    static int State1M2(A& a) { return a.i * 42; }
    static int State2M2(A& a) { return a.i * 420; }

    // The naming sucks, you should find something better

    static constexpr struct {
        void (*Method1)(A&);
        int (*Method2)(A&);
    } State[] = {{State1M1, State1M2}, {State2M1, State2M2}};

    void Method1() { State[s].Method1(*this); }
    int Method2() { return State[s].Method2(*this); }

    int s, i;
};
```

I'm curious if this is even a speedup over a `switch` statement, do benchmark before you adopt it. You really aren't doing something too different from polymorphism, in a rather un-optimized manner, when you start constructing a method table like in the second case.

Comment: It seems that OP actually has multiple methods. If so, wouldn't it be better to have a table of function pointers instead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure, but isn't that just extending this with a container of pointers? As in, its not that far off from the code shown?

Comment: If you mean a single static container for each state, then yes. Storing all the pointers in each object doesn't sound good, when you could have a single vtable pointer instead.

Comment: Yes, this could be an option, but it's a rather verbose method :). There could be several methods and only a few states. But you are right, that I don't know if switch wouldn't be similarly good, since it then could be inlined, I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go with this, use free or static functions, not polymorphy, and encapsulate them with [`::std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). You can even use lambdas, here.

```
class A { 
  public:
    ::std::function<void(A*)> state = func1;
    static void func1(A* that) {
      ::std::cout << "func1\n";
      that->state = func2;
    }   
    static void func2(A* that) {
      ::std::cout << "func2\n";
      that->state = [](A* that) { ::std::cout << "lambda\n"; that->state = func1; };
    }   
  public:
    void method() {
      state(this);
    }   
};
```

However, in most cases a `switch` or `else if` **block would be better** as it can be optimised by the compiler, which may translate it into a jump table. If in doubt, benchmark it!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most versatile solutions available out of the box in c++17, and courtesy of boost prior is the `variant` type and the concept of a `static_visitor`.

Using c++14 and `boost::variant` I have created a very simple state machine that uses type-based switching of code paths plus automatic catching of un-accounted-for state/event combinations.

For a fuller solution I would refer you to the boost fsm header-only library.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct event1 {
};

struct event2 {
};

struct state_machine {

    struct state1 {
    };

    struct state2 {
    };

    struct state3 {
    };

    using state_type = boost::variant<state1, state2, state3>;


    struct handle_event {
        // default case for event/state combinations we have not coded for
        template<class SM, class State, class Event>
        void operator()(SM &sm, State &state, Event const&event) const {
            std::cout << "unhandled event "
                      "state=" << typeid(state).name() << " "
                      "event=" << typeid(event).name() << std::endl;
        }

        template<class SM>
        void operator()(SM &sm, state1 &state, event1 const&event) const {
            std::cout << "received event1 while in state1 - switching to state 2" << std::endl;
            sm.change_state(state2());
        }

        template<class SM>
        void operator()(SM &sm, state2 &state, event2 const&event) const {
            std::cout << "received event2 while in state2 - switching to state 1" << std::endl;
            sm.change_state(state1());
        }

        template<class SM>
        void operator()(SM &sm, state1 &state, event2 const&event) const {
            std::cout << "received event2 while in state1 - switching to state 3" << std::endl;
            sm.change_state(state3());
        }

    };


    template<class Event>
    auto notify_event(Event const&evt) {
        return boost::apply_visitor([this, &evt](auto& state)
                                    {
                                        handle_event()(*this, state, evt);
                                    }, state_);
    }

    template<class NewState>
    void change_state(NewState&& ns) {
        state_ = std::forward<NewState>(ns);
    }


private:

    state_type state_ = state1{};
};

int main()
{
    state_machine sm {};

    sm.notify_event(event1());
    sm.notify_event(event2());
    sm.notify_event(event2());

    // we have not coded for this one
    sm.notify_event(event2());
}
```

example output (exact output will depend on compiler ABI):

```
received event1 while in state1 - switching to state 2
received event2 while in state2 - switching to state 1
received event2 while in state1 - switching to state 3
unhandled event state=N13state_machine6state3E event=6event2
```